# Is it possible to install linux on a steam machine?

Tags: steam, linux, emulation

I would really like to use the system for emulation and GZDoom (especially on the portable steam machine) but it's probably not possible on Steam-OS.

EDIT: I know that Steam-OS is linux, but it is a stripped-down version (no file management, no desktop and no media playback) and I'd rather use something more versatile.

EDIT: I'm an idiot. You can use the desktop and file management in SteamOS (darn you, Forbes for lying).

Comment: I do believe that steam OS is its own Linux Version

Comment: Oops, just saw the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Steam Machines all run a custom version of Debian called SteamOS.

While usually you are jailed within the Big Picture mode, Valve does provide a method to escape to a full-on Linux desktop:

1. Head over to the **Settings** menu: [image]
2. Select **Interface** and check <kbd>Enable access to the Linux desktop</kbd>: [image]
   <sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/enable-access-to-the-linux-desktop-steamos.png))</sub>
3. Now, you can use the **Exit** command to quit to the desktop: [image]
   <sub>(source: [howtogeek.com](https://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/steamos-return-to-desktop.png))</sub>

From here you have access to all of available Linux, including a terminal and whatever apps you want to install. Do note, however, that you have left the safe-haven set up for you by Valve, and you are responsible for your own actions out here.

<sup>Images and steps sourced from [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/179883/how-to-use-the-steamos-desktop/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Steam-Os is running Linux(Debian linux)! The machine pre-installed Steam. Every time you boot up, the system automatically run Steam in Big Picture mode.

Comment: Yes, but Steam-OS is a stripped-down version of linux (no file management, no desktop and no media playback) and I'd rather use something more versatile.

Comment: If that is the case, I think I would say you couldn't.

Comment: I don't see why not because Steam-OS is Debian-based. The problem is that there are no tutorials on it.

Comment: No, I think It's almost impossible to edit a file whilst there is no file management application. If there is a button to open up the terminal, It gets better.

Comment: Some steam machines (Alienware Alpha for example) have USB ports and maybe it's possible to use an live USB with linux.

Comment: It might be possible! http://store.steampowered.com/steamos/buildyourown

Comment: I'm an idiot. You can use the desktop and file management in SteamOS (darn you, Forbes for lying). You are right.

Comment: Gah... Next time, you may search before asking here.

Comment: I should have double-checked my sources.